# About 20 models in 1 django app

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have started work on a local app for myself that runs through the browser. Having recently gone through the django tutorial I'm thinking that it might be better to use django rather than just plain python.

There's one problem: I have at least 20 models and each will have many functions. Quite simply it's going to create one huge models file and probably huge views too. How do I split them up?

The [models are all related](http://woarl.com/images/entity%20chart.png) so I can't simply make them into separate apps can I?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"I have at least 20 models" -- this is probably more than one Django "app" and is more like a Django "project" with several small "apps"

I like to partition things around topics or subject areas that have a few (1 to 5) models.  This becomes a Django "app" -- and is the useful unit of reusability.

The overall "project" is a collection of apps that presents the integrated thing built up of separate pieces.

This also helps for project management since each "app" can become a sprint with a release at th end.

Comment: But if the models have to relate to each other how can I place them in separate apps?

Comment: One model can easily reference models in another package.  You almost always have "higher-level" and "lower-level" models.  Implement the lower-level models in one app.  The higher-level apps can depend on the lower-level app's models.

Comment: Any time you set up a foreign key to the User model in django.contrib.auth, you're relating across separate apps...

Comment: While this answer may oftentimes be the right solution, i disagree with it's totality. I have projects, in which there are 3-4 views, but like 20 modelclasses. Spliting up the models in different apps increases the complexity. why should django need to know of the app's internals? Imho, the correct solution in these cases is indeed splitting up the model.

Comment: "useful unit of reusability" , that is the key reference here for me.

Answer (score 77):

This is a pretty common need... I can't imagine wading through a models.py file that's 10,000 lines long :-)

You can split up the `models.py` file (and views.py too) into a pacakge. In this case, your project tree will look like:

```
/my_proj
    /myapp
        /models
            __init__.py
            person.py
```

The `__init__.py` file makes the folder into a package. The only gotcha is to be sure to define an inner `Meta` class for your models that indicate the app_label for the model, otherwise Django will have trouble building your schema:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'
```

Once that's done, import the model in your `__init__.py` file so that Django and sync db will find it:

```
from person import Person
```

This way you can still do `from myapp.models import Person`

Comment: It's theoretically working but running the line from the tutorial "python manage.py sql gui" doesn't do anything, any idea what's up?

Comment: That usually means that django can't find the models. Make sure you've got the imports in your models.__init__.py file, and that you've set the app_label for each model. Also make sure you've delete the old models.py file.

Comment: This is technically correct, but _almost_ downvote-worthy as it's such a bad idea in practice.  If you have enough models to think about splitting your models.py, you should split into multiple apps.

Comment: Carl, I agree that splitting into multiple apps is valuable in larger projects. S. Lott's points in his post express the benefits of this quite well.

Comment: I think this is useful(convert models.py from a module to a package) in addition to splitting many models into apps. However those cases might not be common. +1

Comment: "I don't see much benefit of splitting things into a bunch of apps, when your models are closely and intrinsically related." – Glenn Maynard

Comment: +1 for answering the question. There are many reasons to split models into separate files. Shop specific coding standards, documentation, and reducing merge conflicts being common ones. I'm not sure how splitting distinct data models into separate physical assets would be bad practice.

Comment: Hmmm... I've been trying this approach... having issues with circular relationships though. How would i fix this?

Answer (score 16):

> The models are all related so I cant's
>   simply make them into separate apps
>   can I?

You **can** separate them into separate apps. To use a model in one app from another app you just import it in the same way you would import django.contrib apps.

Answer (score 5):

Having 20 models in one app might be a sign that you should break it up in smaller ones.

The purpose of a Django app is to have a small single-purpose piece of code, that fits nicelly together.

So, if you had a e-commerce site, you might have a shopping_cart app, a billing app, and so on.

Keep in mind that there is really no problem in apps depending on each other (although it's always better if they can be decoupled), but you should not have an app doing two very distinct things.

The article [Django tips: laying out an application](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/sep/10/django-tips-laying-out-application/) might help you. As always, take everything you read with a grain of salt (including this answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can break up the models over multiple files. This goes for views as well.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* split them into separate files and simply have imports at the top of your main models.py field.

Whether you'd really *want* to is another question.

Comment: As Jarret Hardie said, creating a python package (i.e. a directory with an __init__.py file in it) called models would be the best way to do this.